# Will application created using TideSDK work on Windows XP?

Tags: html, exe, tidesdk

I am planning to create an exe for windows. My problem is my target clients are using windows XP. As windows XP has become too old, it is very difficult to get any support.

Can any one please guide me whether application created using TideSDK works on windows XP or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work. I'm currently working on a project who also target Windows XP. (By the way, it also work on windows 8.1). But in my case (am I doing something wrong?), I've to bundle the app from windows 7 to have an installer.